# how to log a specific controller's action in Yii framework and send it to email address?

Tags: yii

how to log all the events happening in a Yii app's specific controller via a "txt file" or email ?, let's say I have this app made of Yii, now whenever there are users who use the site, I want a particular controller's actions to be logged and send it to me in email . such as the ,

- inserting record
- deleting record
- updating record

so that i will know where exactly to look at whenever an error occured just incase am not around

Comment: use ActiveRecordLog for user model for these oprations and run a cron to mail these files to you

Comment: have you set up `CEmailLogRoute` for errors? I usually find that's enough information on an error.

Answer (score 1):

Yii logging feature is quite handy, did you read this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/topics.logging ?

You should configure `CEmailLogRoute`, for example :

```
array(
  'class'=>'CEmailLogRoute',
  'levels'=>'info',
  'emails'=>'admin@example.com',
  'categories'=>'application.controller.YourController',
),
```

And in your controller actions, simply put :

```
Yii:log('message to log', 'info', 'application.controller.YourController');
```